# C++ Nested DLL function call from C# gives System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll

- My C++ DLL name is `MyDLL.dll`, which is communicating with `TestDLL.dll`
- Now, I want to call functions from `MyDLL.dll` in my C# project

> **Visualization**

```
-----------   communicates    -------------   communicates    ---------------
- C# Code -  -------------->  - MyDLL.dll -  -------------->  - TestDLL.dll -
-----------                   -------------                   ---------------
```

`MyDLL.dll` is written in `C++`
`TestDLL.dll` is written in `C`

> **Here is the Code**

**MyDLL.h**

```
#define MyDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 

extern "C" {
    MyDLL_API int sum(int a, int b);
    MyDLL_API int do();
}
```

**MyDLL.cpp**

```
#include "MyDLL.h"
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" {

    typedef int (CALLBACK* MYFUNC1)(int, int);
    typedef short* (CALLBACK* MYFUNC2)(const char*);

    int MyDLL_API sum(int a, int b) // This function works fine
    {
        return a + b;
    }


    int MyDLL_API do()
    {
        int t = -1;

        HINSTANCE test_dll;
        MYFUNC1 myFunc1;
        MYFUNC2 myFunc1;

        test_dll = LoadLibraryA("c:\\TestDLL.dll");
        if (!test_dll) {
            t=0;
        }

        myFunc1 = (MYFUNC1)GetProcAddress(test_dll, "TestFunc");
        if (!myFunc1) {
            t=1;
        }

        myFunc2 = (MYFUNC2)GetProcAddress(test_dll, "AuthFunc");
        if (!myFunc2) {
            t=2;
        }

        // If I put 'return t' here, it works fine!

        (*myFunc2)("Hello World"); // <-- This line causing the error
        return t;
    }

}
```

**C# Main Program**

```
class Program
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        [DllImport(@"c:\MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "sum")]
        public static extern int Sum(int a, int b);

        [DllImport(@"c:\MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "do")]
        public static extern int Do();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int summation = MyClass.Sum(30, 20); // This runs fine.
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is: " + summation);

        int resultCode = MyClass.Do(); // This causing the ERROR.
        Console.WriteLine("Result code is: " + resultCode);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> **Exception Hint**
>   System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Comment: What are the signatures for `TestFunc` and`AuthFunc`

Comment: Code like `if (!h_dllfunc)` makes excessively little sense, clearly we are not looking at any real code.  Ignoring errors does beget a crash when the OS refuses to co-operate anymore.  You must test this code first in a C++ unit test before you try to do it from C#.

Comment: `TestFunc` and `AuthFunc` are just two functions which are implemented in `TestDLL.dll`
@HasanEmrahSüngü

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I just updated the code. Can you please check now? @HansPassant

Comment: HINSTANCE test_dll;
        MYFUNC1 myFunc1;
        MYFUNC2 myFunc1;

This looks suspicious to me.